# Disable scroll lock

Tags: terminal, keyboard, keyboard-layout

We have a shell/tty based application that has ~1,000 users. It is running in an environment where X Server is not available. If a user accidently turns on the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, it makes it seem as if the application is frozen because it quits responding to keyboard input. Is there a way to disable the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> or remap it to something less intrusive for this use-case?

Comment: You could try fixing the application so it doesn't freeze up when they hit scroll lock...

Comment: @Paul Tobmlin: It's a third party app. The "freezing" is really just a perception by the user. In reality, it's just waiting for keyboard input, which isn't getting through because the Scroll Lock is on.

Comment: In other words, they haven't masked out the key modifiers when Scroll Lock is on.  That used to be a big problem with X programs - they've wait for a particular key and it wouldn't work if the Caps Lock or Scroll Lock key modifier was present.  I've never heard of it happening in a shell/curses app before, but stranger things have happened.

Comment: @Paul: Scroll Lock tends to trigger software flow control on the console.

Comment: You mean like control-S/control-Q?

Comment: @Paul: Correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a GUI env:

Type `xev` on the CLI, then click on the Scroll Lock key to see what its keycode is.

Then use `xmodmap -e 'keycode <value>=<action>'`

Where the `value` is the keycode number you get from the `xev` command.

If you want to desable the Scroll Lock, you should leave the `<action>` as blank.
or you can map the `<action>`  to another keycode.

For example, on my Asus EEE 1005P, the Scroll Lock key is map to `keycode 78` so i would issue `xmodmap -e 'keycode 78='` to disable it.

For a non GUI env:

[setkeycodes](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setkeycodes) `scancode keycode` you get the scancode with the [showkey](http://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey) command. And then you need to use [loadkeys](http://linux.die.net/man/1/loadkeys).
And [here](http://juergenchiu.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-change-keycode-or-keybinding.html) you can find a guide.

I don't have any experience with a non GUI env, hence i gave you the links and a general way on how to do it.

Comment: The application is running in a pure console environment. Will this work if X Server is not running?

Comment: I am think the `xev` program is a GUI app, since it opens a small window in my system. But you always can go with the same keybord and the same OS (just with GUI support), and check what the keycode is.

Comment: xev is an X windows app.  If X isn't running, it won't help you.

Comment: @poke: I have updated my answer to include a non X env, although i am don't have any experience with it. And i would suggest that you edit your question to explicitly include that you aren't looking for a non X solution, since it doesn't help to understand that from the `tty` part.

Answer (score 2):

Disable XON/XOFF (^Q/^S) handling by the tty:

```
stty stop undef
stty start undef
```

Comment: Personally I prefer `stty -ixon -ixoff`.