# How to disable scroll lock for tty terminal

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, tty

I am working on a command line application that runs from a TTY terminal.

The problem is that whenever the user hits the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key the entire program "freezes" until the user disables it again.

This is really annoying and has lead to confusion because the users think that the program crashed.

I assumed this would be an easy fix, but after searching around all I can find is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27160/disable-scroll-lock) answer that is only for GUI applications(The second answer on the post doesn't work at all).

It also seems to suggest that the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> code is device specific, which complicates the matter since it has to work across all possible devices.

The software will run on an arch linux live USB with no GUI. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your application run by users in different environments or only Arch Linux?

Comment: Only arch linux. It is all integrated into a bootable flash drive, so I have complete control over the operating system.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27160/disable-scroll-lock) has a section "For a non GUI env:". Have you tried that?

Comment: Yea, I followed it as best as I could but it didn't work for me. I was a little unclear what they were actually saying to do though.

Comment: If you do not have an alternate layout, I believe you could use `setxkbmap -option grp:sclk_toggle`. This way, ScrollLock now acts to toggle the layouts (i.e., it does nothing if there is only one layout) and not as ScrollLock.

Comment: Cool. I'll try that.